# NotFoundHttpException in RouterListener.php line 125: No route found for "GET /"

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I uploaded my php project in cpanel I get this Error. My `.htaccess` file has this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    #uncomment next line if silex app root is in a mamp subdirectory
    RewriteBase /TeraaketService
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm new to php, how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this in your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /*your_project_name/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

or,

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I get 403 Error with this answer

Comment: this project is just with php